# Python MatPlotLib - axis limits don't work somehow

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a small dataset with random points which I want to plot in a scatter plot. The result now is this:

[image]

This is a bit of a mess, which can be solved by setting the x- and y-axis limits from -1 to 1 (so with zero in the middle). I try to do that with with code:

```
plt.scatter(xitems, yitems)
plt.xlim(-1, 1)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)
```

But the result is this:

[image]

..which is even more depressing. All values are between -1 and 1, so I have no idea why this won't work.

Hope that someone can help.

Comment: Your problem is that your data are strings instead of numbers. You could try `xitems = [float(x) for x in xitems]` (similar for `yitems`)

Comment: You're a hero, that's it! Thanks. In my case I could simply take the entire list and use float to solve this (float(list_items))